# Show the contextmenu of jstree on hover

Tags: contextmenu, jstree

I try to show context menu jstree on hover event with using api context menu plugin, but it doesn't work. Have you any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement the same thing. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
var $treeView = "myTreeList";
$treeView.jstree({
    /* options */
})
.on('loaded.jstree', function() {
    $(".myTreeList a").hover(
        function(){
            $treeView.jstree("show_contextmenu", $(this));
        }
    );
})
```

I just hooked up a hover event to every anchor in the tree when the loaded event fired (don't try to use the li elements or the event on a child will fire along with all it's ancestors). You could also use "on" instead of just hover and you wouldn't need to do this in the loaded event handler but that's what worked for me.